# Is this MIPS assembly code converted from C code correct?

Tags: c, mips

I'm having trouble converting a C code, that contains a function call to another function, into MIPS.

Here is the info:

The function declaration for **go** is **int now(int i, j)**. The C code for the function **now** is:

```
int now(int i, int j, int k, int l){
    return go( go(i, j), k+l);
}
```

Here is my MIPS code so far:

```
now:
    addi      $sp,   $sp,      -8       # adjust the stack to store 2 items
    sw        $ra,   4($sp)             # save return address of func(i, j)
    sw        $t0,   0($sp)             # save register for use afterwards
    move      $a0,   $a0
    move      $a1,   $a1
    jal       go
    add       $t0,   $a2,      $a3      # register $t0 = k + l
    move      $a1,   $t0
    jal       go
    lw        $t0,   0($sp)
    lw        $ra,   4($sp)
    addi      $sp,   $sp,      8
    jr        $ra
```

I'm having trouble with **go(i, j)** being passed as a parameter for the function go

Any inputs would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: why I got marked down? :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question probably doesn't belong on this site, but here's my comments.

```
    sw        $t0,   0($sp)             # save register for use afterwards
```

You don't need to save `$t0`, as it's assumed to be clobbered by functions.

```
    move      $a0,   $a0
    move      $a1,   $a1
```

These two moves do nothing so remove them.

```
    jal       go
```

The call may clobber `a2` and `a3`.

```
    add       $t0,   $a2,      $a3      # register $t0 = k + l
```

Move this statement before the call and change the register to `$s0` and save that register instead of saving `$t0`. If you do that it doesn't matter if `a2` or `a3` get clobbered because you don't need their values anymore.

```
    move      $a1,   $t0
    jal       go
```

You didn't give anything as the first argument in the call. Move the return value of the previous call from `$v0` to `$a0`. Load `$a1` with the value stored in `$s0` as recommended above.

```
    lw        $t0,   0($sp)
    lw        $ra,   4($sp)
    addi      $sp,   $sp,      4
    jr        $ra
```

You saved 2 registers for a total of 8 byte but you're only adding 4 to `$sp`.

Comment: wow finally someone responded, thanks for helping1 I am looking into your comments right now...PS the 4 was a mistake, it's suppose to be 8  bytes :)

Comment: how would I need with the function call go(i, j)?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: Sorry, I mean, how do I deal with the function go(i, j)? I'm not sure what the MIPS code looks like. Thanks

Comment: Just like you were handling it, except you don't need the `move $a0, $a0` and `move $a1,$a1` instructions as they don't do anything. The values you want in the `$a0` and `$a1` registers are already in those registers.

Comment: hey Ross, instead of storing $a2 + $a3 into $s0, you can also store it into $a1, and then call jal go again right? because now function go uses $a0 and $a1???

Comment: The problem is if you do that after the first `jal go` instruction, `$a2` and `$a3` will have been clobbered by `go`. If you do it before the first `jal go` then you'll clobber the value in `$a1` you need to pass to `go`.  If you use `$s0` instead it will be preserved across the call to `go`, but this also means your code needs to save `$s0` so it's preserved across any call to `now`.